# Live in stochastic harmony with your environment

Tags: society, randomness

Let's assume you are in the following situation: You have to decide between two Paths A and B. You know for sure that exactly one path has a return of 1, the other 0. You also know that A has the return of 1 with the chance of 60% and B has the return of 1 with the chance of 40%.

It's clear that if

1. you want to maximize your return
2. you truly believe in your knowledge
3. choosing A or B are pure decisions without side effects, they have no effect other than their return

you choose A.

Is there any theory of "stochastic harmony" that says that you should make your decision with a random generator with 60% for A and 40% for B when 2) or 3) does not hold?

I see this concept often when filtering mathematical densities ( 2) does not hold) and would find it helpful against negative and positive discrimination ( 3) does not hold), but will only go in detail here, when I think that there isn't good theory yet.

Comment: "It is clear that ... you see A and B as slaves in your mind". No, that is not clear at all. What does that mean?

Comment: That means: Choosing A or B has no effect on other things which backfire to you. I edit the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Knowledge however gained affects decision making. In this example the knowledge of the likelihood of getting a positive return would have been gained by trial and error. I don't think human decision making is all trial and error.. I think conscious development does ie from the cradle until we can reason for ourselves and thats when our actions and decision making diverges from the random. If thats what your getting at ? I can't cite any references for this its just my opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret 3 -- within  a utility framework you can include the utility related to the side effects or ignore it, either way you're still just looking at the return.

Comment: when 2) does not hold, why these percentages? ... "harmony" depends on what (kind of) return (and why) you maximize... ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the limit of perfect knowledge, no there is no reason to use a stochastic rule (assuming the agent's goal is to maximize utility).

However, in the case where there is uncertainty in your knowledge, i.e. you've *assessed* the 60/40 split with exactly 0/1 rewards but that assessment may be in error, then there is potential utility to be had from the information gained in exploring the environment.  Usually this is referred to as the [exploitation/exploration tradeoff](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3995763/).

More generally it seems like you're looking for [decision theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_theory) -- which is a pretty well studied and formalized approach for modeling decisions made by agents attempting to optimize a utility.

Answer (score 0):

Bad arithmetic.

Suppose you and I play the game a billion times. I always pick A, so I win 0.6 billion times. You pick A 0.6 billion times and B 0.4 billion times, so you win 0.36bn+0.16bn=0.52 billion times. (All values plus or minus a million or two.) Farewell and thanks for the free 0.08 billion.